# Nintex Regular expression Pattern regex

Tags: regex, sharepoint, workflow, nintex-workflow

May I know how could I extract the file name without the file extension. (i.e`filename`)

from the {WorkflowVariable:File URL} example:

`http://spsite:111/sites/Annual_Leave/Shared%20Documents/filename.pdf`

using Regular expression pattern??

been trying `/[^/]+/[^/]+(?=/[^/]*$)`

but it doesnt seem to work.. thanks!!!!!

Comment: What about `[^/]+\.[^.]*$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You should add this as an answer :)

Comment: Sorry, it should be [`[^/]+(?=\.[^.]*$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5c.%5b%5e.%5d*%24%29&i=http%3a%2f%2fspsite%3a111%2fsites%2fAnnual_Leave%2fShared%2520Documents%2ffilename.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the extraction type step, use

```
[^/]+(?=\.[^.]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5c.%5b%5e.%5d*%24%29&i=http%3a%2f%2fspsite%3a111%2fsites%2fAnnual_Leave%2fShared%2520Documents%2ffilename.pdf).

**Details**:

- `[^/]+` - 1 or more characters other than `/`
- `(?=\.[^.]*$)` - followed with a dot that is followed with 1 or more chars other than a dot and then the end of a string.

Comment: Thank you so much!!